# Dynamic filling of a region of a polar plot

Tags: plotting, filling

I would like to shade area of region as a function of angle using `PolarPlot`.
Here is my attempt.

```
With[
  {pts = 
    Cases[PolarPlot[1 + 2 Sin[θ], {θ, 0, 2 π}], _Line, {0, Infinity}][[1, 1]]},
  Manipulate[
    Show[
      ListLinePlot[{{{0, 0}, pts[[n]]}, pts[[1 ;; n]]}, 
        Filling -> {2 -> {Axis, LightBlue}, 1 -> {Axis, LightBlue}}, 
        PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-0.5, 3.2}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
        PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness@3, Magenta, Magenta], 
        ImageSize -> 500, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], 
        PlotLabel -> Style["r=1+2 sin(θ)", Black, 20]], 
      PolarPlot[1 + 2 Sin[θ], {θ, 0, 2.2 π}, 
        AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness@3}]], 
    {n, 1, Length @ pts, 1}]]
```

[image]

[image]

Two thing I would like to achieve:

1. I don't want to see the yellow highlited region.
2. When inner loop is shaded twice, I would like to make it darker to emphasize that it is the 2nd time.

Any suggestion..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[
  r (1 + 2 Sin[θ]) {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]},
  {θ, 0, thmax},
  {r, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {{-2.25, 2.25}, {-0.5, 3.5}},
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
  ], {thmax, 0.01, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]